# Enable or disable primefaces datatable buttons at the certain row

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces 3.5
Mojarra 2.1.5
jdk 1.6

When my datatable is loading, I need to enable or disable two buttons in the same column at same row.

i.e. When datatable loads the first row, I have to enable down button and disable up button.
When datatable loads the second row till the last row -1, I have to enable both buttons.
When datatable loads the last row I need to enable up button and disable down button.

[image]

Ive tried read the List object and enable,disable but it set enable or disable for all rows.

I would appreciate a help on this. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `rowIndexVar`

Something like this:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.myRows}" rowIndexVar="myRowIndex" var="myRow">
    <p:column headerText="#">
        <h:commandLink styleClass="upArrow" disabled="#{myRowIndex eq 0}"/>
        <h:commandLink styleClass="downArrow" 
            disabled="#{myRowIndex eq myBean.myRows.size()}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel, It worked as expected. The only tip is that size() method does not work in disabled el expression. I had to create  getter/setter i.e. in Down button : disabled="#{myRowIndex eq .myBean.varList} and in backing bean varList = dataTableList.size()-1